# How to selectively disable Angular HTTP Interceptor

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I have an HTTP interceptor that does ref counting on the active requests (+1 for request, -1 for requestError, response, & responseError). The ref count value is used to show/hide a loading overlay. How can I disable this interceptor for some of my requests? For example, after a component is loaded, I want to preload some data in anticipation of what the user's next action will be and I don't want to show the loading overlay - since the loading overlay prevents the user from interacting with the elements on the page.

Comment: The reasonable approach is to have a service that holds one or several properties to switch interceptors on or off.

Comment: @estus yeah, that was an idea I was considering, but even if I toggle a flag to turn off ref counting and then on again before/after the the call to $resource.query, does there exist the possibility of another call updating the ref counting while it's disabled (before it's enabled)? Or... since js is single threaded, is there no way for an async "thread" to hit the refCounter service until the event loop is triggered - in which case, I'm covered? i.e. "Run-to-completion": https://mzl.la/2fbAW7U

Comment: I'm not sure what case you're describing. It depends on whether 'updating the ref counting while it's disabled (before it's enabled)' is synchronous or not. I would suggest to update the question with [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that explains this case.